# php : Retrieving number in the URL

Tags: php, regex

I have url in the following types

```
http://domain.com/1/index.php

http://domain.com/2/index.php

http://domain.com/3/index.php

http://domain.com/4/index.php
```

I need to retrieve only the number from the url .

for example,

when i visit http://domain.com/1/index.php , It must return 1.

Comment: Are 1 2 3 4 a real directories?

Comment: Then I would suggest Daniel Bidulock answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the information provided, this will do what you ask... it's not what I would call a robust solution:

```
$url = $_SERVER['PATH_INFO']; // e.g.: "http://domain.com/1/index.php";
$pieces = explode("/", $url);
$num = $pieces[3];
```

Comment: $url should be retrieved from adress bar,,other part is working fine

Comment: $url = "http://domain.com".$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]; 
$pieces = explode("/", $url);
$num = $pieces[3];
echo $num;

Comment: Happy to help, and thank you for the accepted answer (though I think @Rocket deserves it more)

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php).

```
$url = parse_url('http://domain.com/1/index.php');
```

EDIT: Take a look at `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`, to get the current URL.  Use that instead of `$url['path']`.

Then you can split `$url['path']` on `/`, and get the 1st element.

```
// use trim to remove the starting slash in 'path'
$path = explode('/', trim($url['path'], '/')); 

$id = $path[0]; // 1
```

Comment: $url should be retrieved from adress bar,other part working fine

Comment: @PankajjKumar: Try `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` instead of `$url['path']`.  If that doesn't work `var_dump($_SERVER)`, one of the values will have the path (`'/1/index.php'`).

Comment: $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] returns nothing

Comment: @PankajjKumar: Try `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` (or `$_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]`, or `$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]`) instead.  Use `var_dump($_SERVER)`, to see what values there are, I forget which one is the one you need.

Comment: @PankajjKumar: What returns nothing?  What code is on that page?

Comment: $url = "http://domain.com".$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]; 
$pieces = explode("/", $url);
$num = $pieces[3];
echo $num;

Answer (score 1):

- split the server path by forward slashes (`explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_PATH']);`)
- remove empty entry from the beginning
- take the first element
- make sure it is an integer (`intval()`, or a simple `(int)` cast).

No need to use regular expressions for this.

Comment: $url = "http://domain.com".$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]; 
$pieces = explode("/", $url);
$num = $pieces[3];
echo $num;

Answer (score 0):

You use preg_match() to match the domain and get the 1st segment.

```
$domain = http://www.domain.com/1/test.html

preg_match("/http:\/\/.*\/(.*)\/.*/", "http://www.domain.com/1/test.html");

echo $matches[1];  // returns the number 1 in this example.
```